# Google Map application force show down

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting a problem in my google map application problem.
This is my manifest code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.GPS"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name=".GPS_Testing"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

This is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0trTDjnICco0ZzgjmvY3zTe7PNXzAsoG9iRWtPw"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main program

```
package com.GPS;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPS_Testing extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    /*Create MapView Target*/
    mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

    loc.getLatitude();

    loc.getLongitude();

    String Text = "My current location is:" +

    "Latitud =" + loc.getLatitude() +

    "Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

    Text,

    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

    {

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

    "Gps Disabled",

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

    {

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

    "Gps Enabled",

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:199)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at com.GPS.GPS_Testing.onCreate(GPS_Testing.java:19)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 15:04:08.333: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 15:04:08.341: ERROR/liblog(1207): failed to call dumpstate
```

Comment: put logcat trace as to where you are getting the force close.

Comment: @ PravinCG:If u dont mind,Logcat contain lot of lines so i dont know which line to include

Comment: when it crashes you can see the exception log that would correspond to your application. One way is to filter it based on Error (E button)

Comment: @PravinCG: I have mentioned the logcat above..

Comment: What is the API version you are using plus are you using the correct SDK. You need to use the google API and not the standard one as that does not support maps.

Comment: @PravinCG: i am testing this in my mobile phone set..and the android version is 2.2.1

Comment: your code works for me. I created a project using google API for the API version 8, as you have. I just can suggest creating a new proyect in Eclipse from zero. Sometimes Eclipse can behave extrangly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you right click on Project in Eclipse and the properties and select Android and tell me what is the Project Build Target.

Comment: What happens when you run it on the emulator?

Comment: On emulator it runs smoothly...but on mobile cell it stops unexpectedly

Comment: I have faced something similar on one of the device I have. What is the device and model you are using and can you open any third party application which uses maps on it?

Comment: @PravinCG: Alcatel OT-906 and can you tell how to know if my mobile has Google API or not...I have rooted my cell phone and installed com.google.android.maps and com.google.android.maps.xml and have install map.apk

Comment: The image used is by the device manufacturer has some defect and you can get over it by rooting and installing a custom rom. Search for it on the net and see if you can flash your device with custom mod.